# Adding App state using a child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a Parent component where I set State on 'userData' and pass it to my Child component. Now my Child component does some more work on that data and now it needs to pass a filtered result into a new state props, say allServiceData. I have tried creating a same variable in Parent state and doing 'return setState' on Child, but it doesnt seem to work.
How can I add a new variable with data in the App state using Child component? Is this the right way I should be working with data?

Parent : 
`

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userData: [],
            allServices: [],
        };
      }
<Subs userData={this.state.userData} />
```

`

Child:
`

```
getSub = (data) => {
        let services = this.props.userData.filter(dat => {
            return dat.subscription_id === data;
        }).map(data =>{
            this.setState({
             allServices: services})
        });
  `
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not passing allServices in Subs here but I tried doing that too.. Then I removed it and forgot to add in the snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do [`state lifting`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).
Also,you dont need to `setState` in child component if you don't want to re-render the child component.

Simply pass the filtered data to parent using state lifting.

**Parent:**

```
callParentMethod=(services)=>{

    //do stuff here with services

}
```

render :

```
<Subs userData={this.state.userData} callParentMethod = {this.props.callParentMethod}/>
```

**In Child :**

```
getSub = (data) => {
    let services = this.props.userData.filter(dat => {
        return dat.subscription_id === data;
    })

    this.props.callParentMethod(services);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are filtering your services and then doing a map that is looping through the filtered services and setting the state each time you loop through the filtered services.

Do the filter first and then set the state.

```
getSub = (data) => {
        let services = this.props.userData.filter(dat => {
            return dat.subscription_id === data;
        });

        this.setState({
            allServices: services
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not setState in the child component. Your parent container should have all the setState logic and the child component should be a pure functional component. For updating state in parent component for this scenario you need to pass down a function as props to the child component and access it in the parent component to update the state. Here you will need to move the getSub function to the parent component.
Parent:

```
`getSub = (data) => {
    let services = this.props.userData.filter(dat => {
        return dat.subscription_id === data;
    });

    this.setState({
        allServices: services
    });
 } 

 <Subs userData={this.state.userData}
   getSub={this.getSub} />`
```

in the child component you will need to access it as a props

Comment: So I pass this function in a this.state variable and call it using props ?

Comment: yes getSub function should be in the parent component and child will be accessing it as props for eg in child: 
<div onClick={() => props.getSub(data)}></div>

it is always a good practice to keep child components as pure functions